# Replacement for deprecated function `launchWhenX`

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle, lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

I want to collect flow when the lifecycle reaches specific state. So far I do it like this:

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            viewModel.someFlow
                .onEach { /* it starts collecting flow in STARTED state and never stops */ }
                .launchIn(this)
        }
```

but this function is deprecated. Google recommends to replace it with `repeatOnLifecycle()`, but I don't want to repeat collecting flow every time I reach this state.
I found this link https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/270049505 and tried following solutions:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    lifecycle.withStateAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
        ...
    }
}

lifecycleScope.launch {
    lifecycle.withStarted {
        ...
    }
}
```

I did such a test: I launch the application on a locked screen (and didn't unlock it yet). I expect a `CREATED` state, but the code inside these functions executes. I even myself "lifecycle.currentState" and it is in the state... `STARTED`. In the same scenario, the functions `launchWhenStarted` and `repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)` execute the code only when I unlock the screen. Do I not understand how these functions work or how the lifecycle works or are these functions bugged?